# Sabre Revalidate Itinerary 4.3.0

Tags: sabre

can you please help me if a date change on the segment? anything change
on 2nd flight date is change

```
"Flight": [
            {
              "ClassOfService": "B",
              "Number": 2255,
              "DepartureDateTime": "2023-10-10T07:50:00",
              "ArrivalDateTime": "22023-10-10T11:50:00",
              "Type": "A",
              "OriginLocation": {
                "LocationCode": "JED"
              },
              "DestinationLocation": {
                "LocationCode": "DXB"
              },
              "Airline": {
                "Operating": "EK",
                "Marketing": "EK"
              }
            },
            {
              "ClassOfService": "B",
              "Number": 606,
              "DepartureDateTime": "2023-10-10T21:35:00",
              "ArrivalDateTime": "22023-10-11T00:50:00",
              
              "Type": "A",
              "OriginLocation": {
                "LocationCode": "DXB"
              },
              "DestinationLocation": {
                "LocationCode": "KHI"
              },
              "Airline": {
                "Operating": "EK",
                "Marketing": "EK"
              }
            }
          ],
```

i am facing the following error

> "message": "{"OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS":{"PricedItinCount":0,"BrandedOneWayItinCount":0,"SimpleOneWayItinCount":0,"DepartedItinCount":0,"SoldOutItinCount":0,"AvailableItinCount":0,"Version":"4.3.0","Errors":{"Error":[{"Type":"ERR","ShortText":"Schema Validation Failed","Code":"INVALIDREQ","content":"Invalid request. It is not compliant with schema. 1839\nElement '{http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05}Flight', attribute 'ArrivalDateTime': [facet 'pattern'] The value '22023-10-10T03:45:00' is not accepted by the pattern '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}(:[0-9]{2})?'.\n\n22023-10-10T03:45:00\n[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}(:[0-9]{2})?\n1839\nElement '{http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05}Flight', attribute 'ArrivalDateTime': [facet 'pattern'] The value '22023-10-10T11:30:00' is not accepted by the pattern '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}(:[0-9]{2})?'.\n\n22023-10-10T11:30:00\n[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}(:[0-9]{2})?\n1839\nElement '{http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05}Flight', attribute 'ArrivalDateTime': [facet 'pattern'] The value '22023-10-10T11:50:00' is not accepted by the pattern '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}(:[0-9]{2})?'.\n\n22023-10-10T11:50:00\n[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}(:[0-9]{2})?\n1839\nElement '{http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05}Flight', attribute 'ArrivalDateTime': [facet 'pattern'] The value '22023-10-10T00:50:00' is not accepted by the pattern '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}(:[0-9]{2})?'.\n\n22023-10-10T00:50:00\n[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}(:[0-9]{2})?"},{"Type":"SERVER","ShortText":"27131","Code":"GCB16-ISELL-TN-00-2023-09-01-LQJW","MessageClass":"I","content":""},{"Type":"WORKERTHREAD","ShortText":"7203638827170603095","Code":"TRANSACTIONID","MessageClass":"I","content":""},{"Type":"ERR","ShortText":"Error during Processing","Code":"ERR","content":""}]}},"Links":[{"rel":"self","href":"https://api.havail.sabre.com/v4.3.0/shop/flights/revalidate"},{"rel":"linkTemplate","href":"https://api.havail.sabre.com//shop/flights/revalidate?limit=&offset=&enabletagging="}]}"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've submitted a suggested edit to your question to improve its readability. In future, please familiarise yourself with the markup options available for formatting questions, in particular the use of code fences (3 backticks) to ensure that code is formatted like code rather than prose.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the error message, specifically this bit:

> The value '**22023-10-10T03:45:00**' is not accepted by the pattern '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}(:[0-9]{2})?'.\n\n22023-10-10T03:45:00\n[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}(:[0-9]{2})?\n1839\nElement '{http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05}Flight', attribute '**ArrivalDateTime**'

Or in plain English, the field called `ArrivalDateTime` contains a datetime which has a 5-digit year when the year is expected to be only 4 digits. I'm guessing that this flight isn't really expected to take 20 thousand years :-D